# Context.Session in a Class outside Controller

Tags: session, asp.net-core

In the controller I'm currently using `Context.Session.GetString(*KEY*);`
I have a class that needs to read from a few values stored in the session

I used to use this `HttpContext.Current.Session[*KEY*]`.

I've tried searching in Stackoverflow and MSDN with no luck.

Comment: Are you saying HttpContext.Current.Session is undefined?  It seems like that hasn't changed in asp.net 5.

Comment: Yes I don't get access to Current at all when in a Class.

Comment: And is that class being deployed as part of the same web app where you want to access the session?

Comment: Yes, Same project just a class on its own but can't access HttpContext.Current

Comment: And you're referencing  System.Web.HttpContext.Current?

Comment: There is no HttpContext in System.Web ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx  The namespace.

Comment: I'm using .net 5 that's 4.5 right ? But I don't get anything in system.web. I'm sure asp.net 5 doesn't use system.web

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81760/discussion-between-robert-moskal-and-jordan-coulam).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` doesn't exist anymore in ASP.NET 5, but there's a new `IHttpContextAccessor` that you can inject in your dependencies and use to retrieve the current `HttpContext`: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions/IHttpContextAccessor.cs

```
public class MyComponent : IMyComponent {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public MyComponent(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetDataFromSession() {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(*KEY*);
    }
}
```