# aspnet5 rc1 access session outside controller

Tags: session, controller, asp.net-core, httpcontext

In .Net Framework 4.5 code, System.Web.HttpContext.Current is used, 
In Windows 10, IIS 10, AspNet5 RC 1, System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null.

1. Based on the following link , a class is created with **IHttpContextAccessor** constructor parameter. But from the controller class, which object needs to be passed to the constructor for IHttpContextAccessor? Context object is not available for me, How to access Context object in AspNet5 RC1.
   [Context.Session in a Class outside Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094786/context-session-in-a-class-outside-controller)
2. Outside the controller , is there any way to access session without adding a new constructor parameter, access session like HttpContext.Current.Session["strKey"]?

Answer (score 1):

Project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Startup.cs - Configure(..)

```
app.UseSession();
```

Startup.cs - ConfigureServices(..)

```
services.AddCaching();
services.AddSession();
```

Controller:

> @using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
>
> HttpContext.Session.SetString("myKey", "myValue");

View:

> @using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
>
> Context.Session.GetString("myKey")

Comment: inside the controller, as you said, Session is accessible. But consider this class outside the controller / namespace
`public class Test
    {
        public string Get()
        {        
            return "get value from session";
        }
    }`
Only System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context is available. Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Context is not available. Previously, session was accessible inside that class as  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["key"]