# How to use sessions outside Controller in ASP.net 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Here is what I have now:

```
public bool TokenCorrect()
    {
        var token = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("Token");

        return false;
    }
```

Error:

> an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property

It works in Controllers, but I want to use it in other class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Context.Session in a Class outside Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094786/context-session-in-a-class-outside-controller)

Answer (score 7):

In ASP.NET 5 to get the HttpContext, you would take a constructor dependency on IHttpContextAccessor and have it injected into your component.
Then you need to make sure session is available before using it.
It would be important that your component is scoped per request if using an example like below

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features;

public class Foo
{

    public Foo(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    private readonly HttpContext _context;

    public bool TokenCorrect()
    {
        ISessionFeature sessionFeature = _context.Features.Get<ISessionFeature>();
        if(sessionFeature != null)
        {
            int? token = sessionFeature.Session.GetInt32("Token");
            if(token.HasValue)
            {
                // do whatever check you are doing
            }
        }


        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: if your component is not scoped per request then you would need to keep the HttpContextAccessor around and use it each time you need access the HttpContext

Answer (score 1):

Completely not recommended to be doing it but you could use the `HttpContext.Current` static property to get hold of the current HTTP context:

```
var token = HttpContext.Current.Session.GetInt32("Token");
```

Bear in mind though that this leads to very difficult to unit test code in isolation and is very bad practice to be trying to depend on ASP.NET session in classes that are really not specific to an HTTP context. On the other hand you could perfectly fine have fetched this value from your ASP.NET MVC controller and passed it to this other class as parameter.

Comment: " 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition of 'Current' "

Comment: Make sure that you are using the correct class: [`System.Web.HttpContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: HttpContext does not exist in this namespace... Do I need to add some dependencies in project.json?

Comment: As you can see from the documentation you need to add reference to the `System.Web` assembly in which this class is defined which I totally and absolutely **NOT** recommend you doing in a class library.

Comment: We are talking about ASP.NET 5 and MVC6, this is a bad answer, the @Joe Audette answer should be accepted

Comment: ASP.NET 5 (or, ASP.NET Core 1.0) is a complete, open-source rewrite of the ASP.NET system. `HttpContext.Current` does not exist. You need to use dependency injection to retrieve the context.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpContext` class has a static `Current` property which refers to the current context (if there is one, see below).  So something like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.GetInt32("Token")
```

**However**: Ideally you *shouldn't* rely on this outside of your UI objects.  (You shouldn't even rely on it *in* your controllers, but that can be another story entirely depending on your needs.)  Unless the class you're building is, itself, an interface-driven wrapper for the session to be used in controllers to make them more testable... other classes shouldn't rely on web contexts.

---

**Update:** It looks like this has changed a bit in MVC 6.  Take a look at [this link](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/).  Essentially there is now an `HttpContext` object available to controllers in the `Context` property.  So within a controller you can use something like:

```
Context.Session.GetInt32("Token")
```

Testability is of course still a concern, though it's gotten a lot better.

For non-controller classes, you can inject a context object as an `IHttpContextAccessor`.  Injecting it is a dependency injector concern, of course.  I'm not entirely familiar with the changes in MVC 6 for that, but in general injecting it as a dependency is definitely the way to go.  (In fact, if it's injectable into the controller as a dependency, then you don't need to create a wrapper class anymore because the framework is essentially already doing that for you.)

Comment: Yes, this class will be used in Controllers. Do you think using this is suitable for storing data of currently logged in user?

Comment: @Ludwik11: Abstracting the session access behind an interface is a really good idea, as it helps keep your controllers more testable.  As long as the class is mostly just pass-through access to values and doesn't have any logic that itself needs to be tested, it should be fine.

Comment: Wrong! HttpContext doesn't have a static Current property on MVC6

Comment: @aguafrommars: Interesting.  Looks like this link has some good info on the subject as well: http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/  I'll update the answer in a bit.